# Mysql remove special characters from a set

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to remove a spacial character in my query can anyone help. This is my query

```
select sum(value) from table_1 where id in (1, 2,);
```

This 1,2, is fetch from other table using sub-query.

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear. What do you mean 1,2, came from a subquery? in Mysql? in your programing language?

Answer (score 1):

To remove the trailing colon, you can use [`trim()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_trim):

```
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM '1,2,');
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you want to look for individual values in the list, especially because ids don't usually contain commas.

For that, you can do:

```
select sum(value)
from table_1
where find_in_set(id, '1, 2,') > 0;
```

If the values are coming from a subquery, you would be better off using the subquery directly (in most cases).  The query would be something like:

```
select sum(value)
from table_1
where id in (<subquery>);
```

You would need to modify the subquery to return a list of ids, rather than all concatenated into one field.

Comment: That's fine. The problem is, in database table the value gets stored as 1,2, or 4,5,6, that is each value ends with comma.

Comment: select sum(a.adding) adds from table_1 a,
(
select a.addid from table_2 a, table_3 b where a.id=b.id and b.id=29
) b
where id in (trim(trailing ',' from 'a.addid'))
and b.id=29
group by b.id

Comment: @PrabhaKaran . . . The first version will probably work for what you want.  You might need to remove the spaces, so it would be `find_in_set(id, replace('1, 2,', ' ', ''))`.